# Java JDBC Limited Scanner Function

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc, mysql-workbench

Im a beginner looking to create a scanner that inserts user input data into a MySQL database I've created for a fitness application.

My current database is laid out with the following headings: Date_Created, Program_Name, Excercise_Name, Total_Sets, Set_1_Weight, Set_1_Reps, Set_2_Weight, etc. up to Set 10.

The issue with this is that I only want to scanner query amount of sets input by the user in 'Total_Sets', NOT the full amount of sets (10) in the table.

Thanks.

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with this?

Comment: Tag changed. Should've been Java. Thanks!